# Getting error at NPM publish stage - Your cache folder contains root-owned files

Tags: npm, devops, build-pipeline

```
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/root/.npm"
```

We are using private registry to publish the library. And this error is getting when CD pipeline runs at the time of deployment.

Below stages are running while CD deployment -

```
Clone
Install
lint
Code quality
Pack
Build
Build Image
Scan Image
Publish
```

I cannot share the codebase or working example.
I can share package.json screenshot-
[image]

I tried below options along with npm publish script but no luck-

```
npm cache clean -f

sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/root/.npm"
```

Please help me with this issue